# How i can call API though bouncycastle using signature?

Tags: java, soap, bouncycastle

I have bank API I should call it through SOAP and API Is using security Signature how I can call it I'm new in java ?

I want to create webservice calling API using bouncy castle below how to call API.

curl --request POST \
  --url https://uatapi.alahli.com/uat-api-organization/b2b/account/942 \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-id: REPLACE_THIS_KEY' \
  --header 'x-ibm-client-secret: REPLACE_THIS_KEY' \
  --data '{"MT942StatementRq":{"MT942StatementRqHeader":{"CorporateID":"7552639109693440","CorpReferenceNumber":"6745924877418496"},"MT942StatementRqBody":{"AccountNumber":"6378633726601114","FromDate":"2018-12-01T00:00:00","ToDate":"2018-12-01T23:59:59"}},"Signature":{"SignatureValue":"11.52"}}'

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with bouncycastle. There are many examples on the web of performing HTTPS POST requests using Java's standard libraries as well as other libraries. My personal favorite for most simple HTTP applications is [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html).

Comment: Thx A lot issue with signature this value generate on run time using certificate key